# Python - Lists and For Loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list and a for loop:

```
myList = [“aa,bb,cc,dd”, “ee,ff,gg,hh”]

for item in myList:
    print (“x: %s” % item)
```

The output looks like:

```
x: aa,bb,cc,dd
x: ee,ff,gg,hh
```

My desired output is:

```
x: aa
   bb
   cc
   dd

x: ee
   ff
   gg
   hh
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) functions pretty seamlessly

```
>>> myList = ["aa,bb,cc,dd", "ee,ff,gg,hh"]
>>> for item in myList:
...     print("x: %s" % "\n   ".join(item.split(",")))
...
x: aa
   bb
   cc
   dd
x: ee
   ff
   gg
   hh
```

`split` splits the string into a list based on the delimiter you pass as a parameter, and `join` will join a list into a string, using the string you call it on as a joiner.

Another option would be to just use replace:

```
>>> for item in myList:
...     print("x: %s" % item.replace(",", "\n   "))
...
x: aa
   bb
   cc
   dd
x: ee
   ff
   gg
   hh
```

Comment: No problem anytime !

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the answer above..Another way could look like this:

```
myList = ["aa,bb,cc,dd", "ee,ff,gg,hh"]

for item in myList:
    first, *rest = item.split(",")
    print ("x: %s" %first)
    for r in rest:
        print ("   %s" %r)
```